# javascript function Math.pow taking decimal value from an input text

Tags: javascript, html, input, decimal

I searched a lot on the web on this, but I've not found anything that would help me.
I did this:

```
montante <input type='text' id='A' onkeyup='calcola()' value='15000' /><br />
tasso <input type='text' id='i' onkeyup='calcola()' value='0.07' /><br />
anni <input type='text' id='n' onkeyup='calcola()' value='6' />

<script>
var A = document.getElementById('A').value;
var n = document.getElementById('n').value;
var float i = document.getElementById('i').value;
var R = A / ((1 - Math.pow((1 + i), -n)) / i);

document.write(R);
</script>
```

This works well if you declare the three variables normally, but if you take the values from an input the script does not give the correct answer...
I think the problem is in the function Math.pow that does not recognize the "i" var as a number cause of the dot in the input...
I need this working with the inputs, any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `var float i` is not a real thing. Just do `var i`

Comment: Your problem is that `1 + i` is string concatenation. You should use `parseFloat(i, 10)` to turn the string into a number. (My fellow users: surely there's a duplicate of this somewhere...?)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the value that is read from your html input-elements will be determined by javascript as a String.

If you use the + operator on a variable of type number and a variable of type String, Javascript will perform a string-concatenation:

```
var a = "1";
var b = 2;
var c = a + b;
```

Var c will get the value: "12"

To prevent this behavior you have to to parse the value of your input first. You can do this by using the Javascript [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function.